# 3 Camera Interfacing on Raspberry Pi B for Live Streaming

Tags: camera, motion, mmal

I am new to Raspberry Pi. My basic requirement is to get the live stream from 3 cameras using a Raspberry Pi B. It can be at a low fps. I'm planning to use 2 USB cameras and one RPi Camera Module simultaneously. (Cause using 3 USB Cams using a Hub would consume too much Memory and Power, right?)

So, By far, I've managed to:

1) Interface a USB camera and run **Motion** service and view the live stream on a remote system on the same network.
(using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1jSudsIJfA) tutorial and other help I found online)

2) Interface the RPi Camera Module using **Mjpeg_Streamer**.
(using [this](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/stream-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-to-web-browsers-even-on-ios-and-android) tutorial and other links)

Now, I want to know if I can connect the **RPi camera module** and the **USB webcam**, and **an additional unit of the USB webcam**, and get live stream from all three at 3 different ports. (8081, 8082, 8083, say)

I did some reading on **Motion - MMAL camera** but it will interface only the RPi module and not the USB Cameras because of the large inconsistency in the conf file. I also saw something about **UV4L** somewhere but couldn't really understand much. Basically I want all three to be functional. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

The problem with 3 cameras is that, the first two were USB, but the third is a RPi Camera Module, and I'm unable to run motion for that camera. Basically I need to know **what additional modules do I need to install and what sort of edits do I need to make in the conf file to be able to run Motion for the conventional RPi Camera Module.**

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what is the question? Motion can use a V4L2 interface, and the RPI module have a V4L2 driver `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` (or the UV4L driver you mentionned), and your USB camera have probably a V4L2 interface, then everything should be ok.

Comment: You say you have a live stream from two cameras simultaneously, what's the problem with three?  As mpromonet says, **I don't see a real question here.**  "I have three cameras, any suggestions?" is just too vague.

Comment: Based on your edit, your question has nothing to do with the number of cameras, that there is more than one camera, etc. which makes most of this extraneous.  Don't bother trying to salvage this question, you might as well write another one from scratch and **refrain from describing the irrelevant details of your project.** I'm sure it is interesting, but if you want help with a specific detail, focus on that detail and ask a simple, straightforward, specific, *clear* question.